# Google cloud storage cycling through a directory

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a storage bucket in google cloud. I have a few directories which I created with files in them.

I know that if I want to cycle through all the files in all the directories, I can use the following command:

```
for file in list(source_bucket.list_blobs()):
    file_path=f"gs://{file.bucket.name}/{file.name}"
    print(file_path)
```

Is there a way to only cycle through one of the directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest studying the [Cloud Storage list API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects) in more detail.  It looks like you have only experimented with the most basic use of [list_blobs()](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html#google.cloud.storage.client.Client.list_blobs).  As you can see from the linked API documentation, you can pass a prefix parameter to limit the scope of the list to some path.  `source_bucket.list_blobs(prefix="path")`:

Comment: thanks i did not know about this api documentation, only saw the basic stuff on the cloud website